# powershell compare file date not working consistently

Tags: powershell

I'm running into a strange issue while comparing the last write time of files using the month format. The comparison seems to work for some file dates when the dates are very different but not if they are close like a few months apart. I was wondering if anybody had any suggestions? As always, any help would be appreciated.

```
[datetime]$UpdateFileDate = (Get-ItemProperty -Path  $FileUpdatePath).LastWriteTime
[datetime]$InstalledVersion = (Get-ItemProperty -path $FilePath).LastWriteTime
$file = Get-Date $UpdateFileDate -Format Y
$version = Get-Date $InstalledVersion -Format Y 

if ($version -lt $file) {

$Process = Start-Process -FilePath $FileUpdatePath -PassThru
Wait-process -InputObject $Process

}
```

Comment: you are using a ... _horribly_ wrong method of comparing the months. [*grin*] you are comparing the NAME of the month followed by the year [February, 2019] ... and that is a _STRING_. you already had the items as datetime objects ... so why don't you compare that? [*grin*] try this `(Get-Item -LiteralPath C:\Temp\FXSAPIDebugLogFile.txt).LastWriteTime.Month` for getting the month NUMBER and then comparing that to the same info from the other source.

Comment: Hi Lee_Dailey. Thanks for the suggestion. Is there any way to get the month and year? I am working with some files that can be quite a few years out of date and need to be updated.

Comment: do you need to ignore the day? if not, then simply use the `.LastWriteTime` as-is. [*grin*] ///// if you want to use the date, but not the time, use `.LastWriteTime.Date` to get the date with the time set to midnite. //// if you absolutely need just the year-month, this will do it >> `Get-Date (Get-Item -LiteralPath C:\Temp\FXSAPIDebugLogFile.txt).LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyy-MM')`

Comment: Yes, I do need to ignore the day. I have to do the comparison by month and year. I will try your suggestion. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you are welcome! glad to have helped a little ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to not include the day part in the dates to compare, I suggest you do something like below.
It converts the dates to always be day 1 of the month. The cast with `[datetime]` ensures you are indeed comparing date objects, not strings.

```
# of use something like this:
# $fileDate = [datetime]('{0:MM/01/yyyy}' -f (Get-Item -Path $FileUpdatePath).LastWriteTime)

$fileDate    = [datetime](Get-Date ((Get-Item -Path $FileUpdatePath).LastWriteTime) -Format 'MM/01/yyyy')
$installDate = [datetime](Get-Date ((Get-Item -Path $FilePath).LastWriteTime) -Format 'MM/01/yyyy')

if ($installDate -lt $fileDate) {
    $Process = Start-Process -FilePath $FileUpdatePath -PassThru
    Wait-process -InputObject $Process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Lee_Dailey and Theo for your help. I used a hybrid solution that uses parts of both answers. I changed the string to a double. This makes it a simple mathematic comparison. Much easier to follow.

```
[datetime]$UpdateFileDate = (Get-ItemProperty -Path  $FileUpdatePath).LastWriteTime
[datetime]$InstalledVersion = (Get-ItemProperty -path $FilePath).LastWriteTime
[double]$file = Get-Date $UpdateFileDate.ToString('yyyy.MM')
[double]$version = Get-Date $InstalledVersion.ToString('yyyy.MM')

if ($version -lt $file) {

$Process = Start-Process -FilePath $FileUpdatePath -PassThru
Wait-process -InputObject $Process

}
```